# Flatline: How to calculate days between two dates

Tags: date, machine-learning, bigml

I want to add a calculated field in a [BigML](https://bigml.com/) datasheet with the result of days between two dates. 
I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the number of days between two date fields with [Flatline](https://flatline.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-manual.html#datetime-arithmetic) language but I don't know how to do it even reading the doc.

Any clue about how create this calculated field?

PS: Somebody with enough reputation could create and add tags "bigml" and "flatline"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the only way to subtract dates is by first transforming them to an
epoch (number of milliseconds since 1970) and then computing the difference:

```
   (- (epoch "12/03/1990") (epoch "01/01/1988"))
```

That will give you the number of milliseconds between the two dates, which then
can be transformed to other units.  What that won't give you is of course the
difference in calendar days: we don't have yet in Flatline a way of subtracting
calendar dates.  But it shouldn't be too difficult to add them if it's a feature
you need :)